How to change background-color of `p-card` component in PrimeNG 18?
I am trying to change the background color of the container of p-card component.
For context, I am brute forcing to change some styling in primeng components just to see if I will be able to have that flexibility just before diving into a project. The problem is, sometimes I can style the components the way I want to, but sometimes I don't know how and why the specificity in CSS doesn't work.
This works:
p-button { 
  margin: 1rem;
}

But not this:
p-card div.p-card-body { 
  background-color: purple;
}

Even specifying !important doesn't work.
Versions: Angular 18 && PrimeNG 18.0.0-beta.2
Can anyone help? I have not seen any good guide on the internet.

Where do you place the mentioned CSS? In component, global stylesheet? Would be great to reproduce in StackBlitz. Thanks.

in the primeng library you can make use of the [style] property to change the color or even inject style to the plugin
ie,
<p-card header="Simple Card" [style]="{ background: 'purple' }" >
  <p class="m-0">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </p>
</p-card>

here the [style]="{ background: 'purple' }"  will do the action needed here.
im adding a stackblitz example here for clarity here

One way to increase the specificity in CSS when !important doesn't work is to repeat the class name, you can try this:
.p-card.p-card div.p-card-body.p-card-body { 
  background-color: purple !important;
}

Another solution would be to use ::ng-deep:
::ng-deep .p-card .p-card-body {
  background-color: purple !important;
}

